# Problem with XML-parsing using Beautiful Soup

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When trying to replace some elements in an XML with Beautiful Soup, I found out that I have to use `soup.find_all().string.replace_with()` to replace the desired elements. However, I came across the problem that the `soup.find_all()` method only returns elements of type `None`.

So I tried to break my problem down to an XML that is as basic as possible:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

xml = """
<xml>
    <test tag="0"/>
    <test tag="1"/>
</xml>"""

soup = BS(xml, 'xml')
for elem in soup.find_all("test"):
    print('Element {} has type {}.'.format(elem, elem.type))
```

Which gives the exact same thing:

```
Element <test tag="0"/> has type None.
Element <test tag="1"/> has type None.
```

I'd be happy, if someone could point out, where the problem lies.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to replace here?

Comment: also are you looking to use `.name` instead? `print('Element {} has type {}.'.format(elem, elem.name))`

Comment: Sorry, should have made that more clear. What I'm trying to do is to replace, for example, `tag="0"`with `tag="2"`. In this example I would do this by using `elem.string.replace_with('test tag="2"')` inside the for-loop. However, this just gives `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'`.

Comment: ok, well I put a solution on the bottom. That should get you going, but I'll adjust it to reflect the example output you provided

Comment: the issue is, `"test tag="2"` is not a string/text in that tag/element. It's an attribute. So what you're really trying to replace is not the string/text, but the attribute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for as an output, but you can replace tag attributes the following way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

xml = """
<xml>
    <test tag="0"/>
    <test tag="1"/>
</xml>"""

replace_list = ['0']
replacement = '2'

soup = BS(xml, 'xml')
for elem in soup.find_all("test"):
    if elem['tag'] in replace_list:
        elem['tag'] = replacement
    #print('Element {} has type {}.'.format(elem, elem.name))

xml = str(soup)

print (xml)
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<test tag="2"/>
<test tag="1"/>
</xml>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. By the time I saw your answer, I came to a solution by myself, using `elem.attrs['tag'] = '2'`. I would need to specify different replacements for different elements, but that shouldn't be a problem.